# Kotlin ListView item click based on String

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Is there a way to check which string was clicked within a simple `ListView`? I want something different to happen for each item in this `ListView` (when clicked) but I've not seen any relevant/helpful tutorials. I understand that a `when` block would be necessary for this but unsure of the best way to implement it.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var array = arrayOf("Melbourne", "Vienna", "Vancouver", "Toronto", "Calgary", "Adelaide", "Perth", "Auckland", "Helsinki", "Hamburg", "Munich", "New York", "Sydney", "Paris", "Cape Town", "Barcelona", "London", "Bangkok")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview_item, array)

        val listView:ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview_1)
        listView.setAdapter(adapter)

        listView.onItemClickListener = object : OnItemClickListener {

            override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
                            position: Int, id: Long) {
                    ????
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_listitem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/listitem_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_title"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your listview_item.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `onItemClick()`, the `position` parameter is the position in the data set that was tapped. So you ought to be able to index into your array to get the tapped string:

```
val tappedString = array[position] // will be "Vienna" when position is 1
```

If you want to verify that the clicked item has a certain value, you can similarly do this:

```
if (array[position] == "Vienna") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use position numbers. Strings are easier in this scenario as some names will need to change in the future

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You have an array of strings: `var array = arrayOf("Melbourne", "Vienna", ...)`. Therefore, `array[0]` is "Melbourne" and `array[1]` is "Vienna". Indexing into an array is the whole point of an array. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: It's a little suspicious that the array variable is read-write. Maybe the length can change, too, which would create issues if the array changes, but isn't updated in the adapter immediately.

Comment: Could use `val tappedString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()` to avoid the risk of non-synced data.

Comment: The order of the items will need to change at some point. `when (position) {
            0 -> {` etc. is what I used before. Why isn't it simple to do that but with `Strings`? That's what are used as the data.

Comment: When the order of items changes, you'll have to interact with the adapter in some way (either by calling e.g. `add()` or `clear()` etc along with a `notifyDataSetChanged()` or by creating a whole new `ArrayAdapter` and re-assigning it to the list). Then your `OnItemClickListener` should reflect those changes too.

Comment: I know but I don't mean during runtime. I'm thinking about code maintenance. This can be done with a `when` block.

Comment: @MacaronLover I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding here. If you change the order of your `array`, the posted answer will just work.

Comment: `position` is what it says: the numerical position of each element in the list. Whether your data is a set of `String` or `Object` or anything else, there will always be a _first_ thing, and then a _second_ thing, etc.

Comment: Can the `position` be something else?

Comment: I want to check by `String` name, not position number. With long lists, it's much easier to check by name rather than trying to rember what position a specific `String` is.

Comment: @MacaronLover are you saying you want to do something like `if (tapped == "Vienna")` ? Then you could do `if (array[position] == "Vienna")`. You don't have to check `if (position == 1)`.

Comment: @BenP. Cool but why is it when I use `getString(R.string.vienna)` I get this error? `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Just to clarify, `if (array[position] == "Vienna")` is the solution

Comment: @MacaronLover I've updated my answer with information based on this discussino.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `position` and `array` then you can get the text from the View.

Try this:

```
override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View,
                        position: Int, id: Long) {
    val textClicked = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.listitem_title).text.toString()
    when (textClicked) {
        "something1" -> TODO()
        "something2" -> TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: What about checking if the clicked item is a specific `String` name?

Comment: Does this help now?